# Using Travis Ci with GitHub Pages Error: gh-token is invalid

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, github-pages

I'm setting up my Travis Ci integration with my GitHub pages repo and I'm getting this error when committing to my dev branch, which on completion should automatically commit to my master branch.

My Error:
`gh-token is invalid. Details: GET https://api.github.com/user: 401 - Bad credentials // See: https://developer.github.com/v3`

My git flow is as follows:
I use dev as an intermediary branch. The application is using vue.js and required a production build, which the production build is what should be pushed to master.

- push local branch to remote branch
- create a pull request on remote feature branch to the dev branch
- merge feature branch with dev branch (this is when Travis CI should push to master)

Here is my current .travis.yml

```
if: branch = dev
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "lts/*"
cache:
  directories:
    - "node_modules"
script:
  - set -e
  - npm run build
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  github_token: GITHUB_TOKEN
  keep_history: true
  local_dir: build
  target_branch: master
  on:
    branch: dev
```

I've confirmed my GitHub access token and tried increasing permissions. The token I'm currently using only has public repo access, which is based on the Travis CI docs

Answer (score 0):

Might be an easy fix.

Have you tried access `GITHUB_TOKEN` like an environment variable?

```
  github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN
```